# Search module issue

Tags: 7, search

I am using drupal search module, when I searched for let say "MG-1055" (this is one of my product's article number) it successfully display the results but if I try to search only "MG" or "1055" then it did not search.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal's core search don't allow faceted search. It should be replaced with

- [Apache Solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) or
- [Elastic Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/elasticsearch_connector)